# jquery fading span does not contain the image if size changes dynamically

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to fading effect in image gallery section. It's ok but if image height is higher span does not contain the all image. [Here is the page link](http://goo.gl/NZszp9).

And, here is my jquery code for finding image size:

```
 // ON MOUSE OVER
$(".roll").hover(function () {

// SET OPACITY TO 70%
var  height=$('.img-galeri').height();
var  width =$('.img-galeri').width();
$(this).height(height);
$(this).width(width);
$(this).stop().animate({
opacity: .7
}, "slow");
},
```

thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're getting the height and width you're doing so universally, you need to specify just the image you're covering.

Try changing your code to this:

```
// ON MOUSE OVER
$(".roll").hover(function () {

// SET OPACITY TO 70%
var  height=$(this).parent().children(".img-galeri").height();
var  width =$(this).parent().children(".img-galeri").width();
$(this).height(height);
$(this).width(width);
$(this).stop().animate({
opacity: .7
}, "slow");
},
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a dumb mistake. It's "children", not "child". Try now?

Comment: thank you it works now. but it is interesting, first we are going one step back and then going 2 steps forward. :) thanks for help.